# Tomcat and multiple domains/applications

Tags: tomcat

Currently I run single tomcat with single WAR application on port 80.  The domain name *www.foo.org* is pointed to this server ip.

What is the procedure of adding *www.bar.org* domain for a different client on port 80?

Thank you

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From the beginning you have a single "Host" record in your *conf/server.xml* for `localhost`

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Now you can add another "Host" records, for example

```xml
  <Host name="anotherclient.com"  appBase="anotherclient" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="anotherclient_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

where `name="anotherclient.com"` is the new client's domain, and `appBase="anotherclient"` is its web application root directory name (where you deploy your war); it is relative to the tomcat home dir.

Changes will be accepted after tomcat is restarted.

Requests going to any other domains (not listed in `server.xml`) but pointing to IP address of your server will be passed to the default application, it is specified in the `Engine` element

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
```

Comment: Does this mean that the wars are at `/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war` for the original foo.org site, and then `/opt/tomcat/anotherclient/ROOT.war` for the new bar.org site?

Comment: @CodeMed Yes, that is correct. I just tried this myself and putting the WARs like that seems to work for me.

Comment: we have to create that directory anotherclient ourself or it's creating after restarting tomcat7

Comment: An empty directory won't be very useful without `war` inside it, thus just create it and deploy your `war` there. Then restart tomcat.

Comment: Works nicely! But why not keep the "webapps" folder and telling the correct webapp using `<Context path="" docBase="web-app-1" debug="0" privileged="true" />` ? I use this, having my webapps all under "webapps" (which I am used to for forever). Is this rather bad practise? (Note: I am using Tomcat 8.5, maybe it wasn't even possible back in the day with tc7, I don't know)

Comment: @BAERUS, where did you put that statement in exactly ??!

Comment: @Axel I have several hosts in the tomcats server.xml. Each looks like this: <Host name="www.my-url.xyz" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Context path="" docBase="my-web-app-1/2/3..." debug="0" privileged="true" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host> Like this I map an url to an application, all under "webapps".

Comment: @BAERUS I have the same case as yours but when I change server.xml files as you said. the Domain is pointing to Tomcat Homepage instead of a particular project. Can you please help?

Comment: I fear I can't really help anymore, as this entire (private) project I did is long in the bin. And from memory I can't say anything :/ I am sorry!

Answer (score 6):

In its default configuration, Tomcat accepts requests for any hostname and sends them all to the "localhost" <Host> defined in conf/server.xml. If you haven't change that, then all you have to do is make sure that you have DNS records set up for both hostnames to point to your server.

If you want to have a different set of webapps for each hostname, then you'll have to define a second <Host> in conf/server.xml and use the appropriate hostname for it. (Note that you'll always have to have a "default" host where all requests go that don't match any of the explicitly-defined hosts).

You can read the documentation for <Host> here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html (That's for Tomcat 7.0.x. You didn't mention your version so I gave you a link to the latest version's documentation).

Comment: Thank you - Its version 7,   What about the WAR files? each client need a diffarent deployment?

Comment: @user648026 Each <Host> gets its own appBase, so you can choose to put your WAR files in either or both of them. Choosing one will make that WAR file only accessible using the hostname of that <Host>, while putting the WAR file in both means that you will have two copies of the webapp running simultaneously in the same container: one for one host, and one for the other.

Comment: So single tomcat running on port 80 can handle multiple hosts on the same port (80) with single WAR, using multiple "hosts" configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you have a tomcat (or other application server) on port different from 80 (like 8080 or 7001 or anything you want).
After that you put a web server (like apache http server) on port 80 and configure one or many connector to point to different port on different application server with different address.

For Apache http + tomcat you can take a look at this link:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Comment: There's no particular reason to add another product to the OP's environment: this problem can be solved using Tomcat alone.

Comment: That's just a best practice in professional environment to have web and application server.

Comment: Malarkey: Tomcat is a perfectly acceptable web server. Calling something a "best practice" does not make it a best practice. It's a /common/ practice, but certainly not a "best" practice.

Comment: Another alternative to running Apache + Tomcat to forward traffic from port 80 to 8080 is to use NAT tables and translate all traffic coming on port 80 to port 8080. Even though Apache is fast NAT is faster and it is already a part of iptables (I am assuming your server is linux).