# How to change server/host for HttpServlet on the basis of condition

Tags: java, spring, http

By using HttpServlet request.getServerName(), I am getting my current server. Is there any way to change that server/host. My spring view is a jsp file.
Lets say my domain is

```
www.mydomain.com
```

and my spring view is some jsp file.
Now when I return view file name using ModeAndView like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("somefile.jsp",responseJSON);
```

It opens the resultant view in same domain/server using my somefile.jsp view i.e

```
www.mydomain.com/some_results
```

But I want to change the server/host according to some conditions. Like if some condition satisfies, I want it to be opened in some other domain/server using the same somefile.jsp view i.e.

```
www.someOtherDomain.com/some_results
```

Basically what I want is to change the server without redirection. Is there any way out or some method to change the server. I am very to new to networking stuff.

Comment: What do you mean "change server without redirection"? The domain that is displayed is determined by what the browser asked. If the browser asked for a certain domain, your response can either give it a page in that domain, or tell it to look in another domain (a redirect). The response doesn't include a domain name if it is not a redirect statement.

Answer (score 0):

I want to start off by saying, what I think you are trying to achieve is normally done this way: [Tomcat and multiple domains/applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704833/tomcat-and-multiple-domains-applications). That approach would have two applications running on one application server. The application server (ex. Tomcat) would route the request to the appropriate application.

That said however, I believe what you are trying to ask is how to have a single server with a single application respond to two domains, with certain resource responses being dynamically tailored. If indeed this is what you are trying to do, you are off to the right start; you now just need to add some logic to toggle which response is sent using what you know from the request.

```
public String whereAmI(ServletRequest request) {

    String response;
    String theServer = request.getServerName();

    if (theServer.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")) {
        response = "You are on your dev system";
    } else {
        response = "You are not on the dev system.";
    }

    return response;
}
```

Note: In JDK 7+, you can also use a [switch statement with String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) if desired.